# How would I prove that this is a group?

Tags: group-theory

From what I know a group must be associative, have an identity element, and have an inverse for each element in the group.

Say I have a group $G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ (the Cartesian product of the integer numbers).  The binary operation will be $(a,b)*(c,d) = (a^c, d^b + (-5)^a)$ (I just made this up so it may not be a group).

To prove that the above is a group would I simply need to prove that it is

1. Associative $((a,b)*(c,d))*(e,f) = (a,b)*((c,d)*(e,f))$
2. Has the identity element $(a,b)*(e1,e2) = (a,b)$
3. Has an inverse for each element $(a,b)*(a^{-1},d^{-1})) = (e1, e2)$

Is this correct?  Also, please correct me if something I wrote was incorrect.

Comment: You also need the operation to be closed.  For your definition it's easy to see that the result will be an ordered pair of integers, but for other definitions it's not obvious.

Comment: the operation must be internal, results of any operations, identity and all the reverses must belong to the set. Then the formulation *it has* is not the best.
indeed, it's not a group, there is no neutral element

Comment: Do both parts e1 and e2, (e1, e2) of the identity element have to be the same?  Also, can there be more than one identity element?